# How to implement spatial indexing for triangles

Tags: python, mesh, delaunay, spatial-index

I would like to implement spatial index for triangles (unstructured mesh) for point search to use in linear TIN interpolation. Is there any python library or code available to understand this. I tried `scipy.spatial.delaunay`, but I don't want to generate triangulation again.